# How to set proxy in scrapy shell, not in settings.py

Tags: python, scrapy

I had set proxy in settings, but I want to test some in scrapy shell, so what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to that directory where your project is located and from there execute scrapy shell command. That would do the trick.

Comment: Thanx very much, it's very helpful to me.I do this as you say, it works!